# Creating "Hovercards"

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I would like to create a similar feature to Facebook's own hovercards, where you hover your mouse over a certain sentence and it pops up with a little window right above the text containing some information.

I wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction here for creating something similar.

Facebook Hovercard:

[image: Facebook Hovercard]

Comment: So like a *ToolTip* ; http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Comment: I don't use jQuery UI, so I wouldn't know. :) I'll check it out though.

Comment: I mention it as ToolTip is the standard term for that type of UI element so would be more googleable.

Comment: Are you using any framework (jquery, angularjs), or just pure JS?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks I'll definitely look at it and experiment.

Comment: @giordanolima Pure JS at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to create those cards (if they are static) as they are. Just make them visible in the first step, design them.

The second step is to make `display:none` to all of them.

Later on, if you hover over certain texts, then call a JS function which changes the CSS to `display:block;`

This in case that you don't want dynamic data or content, this is just the simplest solution. From there, you can start thinking of make it more advanced.

> 1. Style the cards as they would be visible all the time
> 2. Hide them with display:none;
> 3. Call a JavaScript function when you hover over text/links and change the CSS to display:block

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a mess around! And yes the information is static.

Answer (score 0):

Check out qTip<sup>2</sup>.  Here's a link to their demo page:

http://qtip2.com/demos